# Odd behavior while calling ExpressJS REST route

Tags: node.js, api, rest, express, themoviedb-api

I'm making a simple REST server that wraps around the APIs of [TMDb](https://www.themoviedb.org/). And I'm using [MovieDB](https://github.com/impronunciable/moviedb/) Node module which has functions to directly call APIs of TMDb by providing just API key.

I have following app folder structure.

```
myproject
|
---configuration.json
---index.js
---app.js
---/routes
     |
     --- index.js
     --- /movie
           |
           --- index.js
```

In `myproject/index.js`, I have script that simply starts Express server, and `app.js` is where I'm initializing routes.

### myproject/app.js

Here's how routes are initialized.

```js
var myApp = require("express")(),
    configuration = require("./configuration.json");

myApp.locals.tmdbApiKey = configuration.tmdbApiKey;
myApp.use('/api', require('./routes'));
```

As shown above, server will have API root as `localhost:9000/api/` (I'm running it on port `9000`).

### myproject/routes/index.js

Here's how I'm loading routes for `movie`.

```js
var router = require('express').Router();
router.use('/movie', require('./movie'));
```

### myproject/routes/movie/index.js

And finally, I have defined end-points as follows.

```js
var router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/genrelist', function(req, res) {
    var tmdb = require('moviedb')(req.app.locals.tmdbApiKey);

    tmdb.genreList(function(err, tmdbRes) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(tmdbRes);
    });
});

---
---
```

### Usage

Now, calling `http://localhost:9000/api/movie/genrelist` should respond me with list of Genres that TMDb API provides, via `moviedb`'s `genreList()` method, in case my understand of routes and map of route is correct.

However, I'm getting following response.

```json
{
  "original": null,
  "response": {
    "req": {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/genrelist"
    },
    "header": {
      "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
      "cache-control": "public, max-age=28800",
      "content-type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
      "date": "Wed, 15 Jun 2016 11:33:51 GMT",
      "etag": "\"37a6259cc0c1dae299a7866489dff0bd\"",
      "server": "openresty",
      "status": "404 Not Found",
      "x-memc": "MISS",
      "x-memc-age": "0",
      "x-memc-expires": "28800",
      "x-memc-key": "35bba1a0c9464e4e471cdb466209d8b3",
      "x-ratelimit-limit": "40",
      "x-ratelimit-remaining": "38",
      "x-ratelimit-reset": "1465990436",
      "content-length": "84",
      "connection": "Close"
    },
    "status": 404,
    "text": "{\"status_code\":34,\"status_message\":\"The resource you requested could not be found.\"}"
  },
  "status": 404
}
```

If you see value of `response.req.url`, it tried calling `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/genrelist` which is obviously incorrect as TMDb API doesn't have any such end-point.

However, if I change my `router.get` within `myproject/routes/movie/index.js` to something like this:

```js
var router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/top_rated', function(req, res) {
    var tmdb = require('moviedb')(req.app.locals.tmdbApiKey);

    tmdb.miscTopRatedMovies(function(err, tmdbRes) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(tmdbRes);
    });
});
```

It works just fine, notice that I also changed call from `genreList()` to `miscTopRatedMovies()`. Shockingly, if I keep call to `genreList()` as it is, then also it retrieves list of `top_rated` movies.

Even scary part is that I'm doing `console.log()` within GET method and it doesn't log anything. Even debugging the server using `node-debug` doesn't break execution if I set break-point within GET. So I have feeling that my REST calls via REST client are directly translated to TMDb API calls (may be due to identical REST signatures) and MovieDB is not getting called at all, I'm not 100% sure though.

So, to identify if something is wrong with MovieDB module itself, I created simple JS file that directly uses MovieDB, and ran it with `node` command, and it worked fine for all the methods I'm using.

So what is wrong that I'm doing here?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using webstorm? I've had similar spooky WTF moments because of webstorm caching

Comment: @pulse0ne No, I'm using Atom editor and Terminal run and debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the problem was, and it was a silly one.

In my Movie routes, I had one end-point as follows.

```js
router.get('/:movieId', function(req, res) {
    // Call tmdb.movieInfo()
});
```

And remaining end-points also started with `/`, as follows.

```js
router.get('/popular', function(req, res) {
    // Call tmdb.movieInfo()
});
```

So clearly, it is a bad design and will cause troubles, since `/:movieId` will be invoked when a valid movie ID is passed, but I also have other points which use keywords (exact same as TMDb), so when I tried GET on `/popular`, MovieDB internally called API as determined by TMDb (`/api/movie/popular` is valid end-point for TMDb too), and hence I got results correctly.

However, if I do GET on `/genres`, my API thought of word `genres` as a `/:movieId`, due to identical signature, and as no such ID exists, it failed.

I have now corrected my end-point as

```js
router.get('/info/:movieId', function(req, res) {
    // Call tmdb.movieInfo()
});
```

And everything works as expected.

Lesson learned, never have identical end-points where param values and keywords are involved.